# How to reduce sparsity in document term matrix in which corpus is large (R)

Tags: r

I have a corpus with a little over 15,000 text documents.  The removeSparseTerms function does not work:

```
dtm

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 15095, terms: 12811)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 140286/193241759
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 37
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.1)
dtms

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 15095, terms: 0)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 0/0
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 0
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

I also tried this, which didnt work:

```
colTotals<- col_sums(dtm)
dtm2 <- dtm[,which(colTotals>20)]
dtm2

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 15095, terms: 1387)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 100867/20835898
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 26
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Is there anything else I can do to decrease sparsity?  I want to be able to open up the frequency sheet in excel and right now it requires too much memory so I can't open (which is why I want to reduce the sparsity).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and in my case increasing the sparsity helped (because the frequency of terms in my document was quite low). Instead of `dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.1)` try this: `dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.99)`

Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160539/is-this-interpretation-of-sparsity-accurate for a clear definition of sparsity ("sparsity refers to the threshold of relative document frequency for a term, above which the term will be removed.")